# Hyper-V - Can a local user group contain a domain group as a member?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012

Can a local user group contain a domain group as a member?

Situation is this: Server 2012 has Hyper-V role installed, logon as non-Admin cannot access Virtual Machine Manager because of error:

> you do not have the required permission

I can solve this by adding the user to the local 'Hyper-V Administrators' group which works fine but I would prefer to do this at the domain level.

So for example can I have a Domain\Hyper-V Administrators group which is a member of the local\Hyper-V Administrators group.  Or perhaps I can somehow give appropriate permissions to run VMM to the Domain\Hyper-V Administrators group?

Answer (score 2):

Local groups on domain member computers can have groups (Global, Domain Local, or Universal) from the domain nested within them. Creating your "DOMAIN\Hyper-V Administrators" group is certainly a viable idea.

You should look into using "Restricted Groups", which can allow you to perform this group nesting automatically on your domain-joined Hyper-V hosts. [This HOWTO is nice](http://gpfaq.se/2007/09/09/how-to-using-restricted-groups/), though it doesn't drive home the point hard enoguh that you'll really want to use the "This group is a member of" functionality more often than not.

Comment: Problem seems to be that local 'Hyper-V Administrators' group on hyper-V host server cannot have 'domain\Hyper-V Administrators' group added as a member: 'Built-in groups cannot be added to other groups'.  Tried using Restricted Groups GPO but seems same problem.

Comment: That sounds like you're trying to add "MACHINE\Hyper-V Administrators" to the "DOMAIN\Hyper-V Administrators" group. Odd... I can confirm that I have a domain group nested into the local "Hyper-V Administrators" group on a Hyper-V 2012 machine.

Comment: I am trying to add 'Domain\Hyper-V Administrators' as a member of 'VMHost\Hyper-V Administrators' but 'Domain\Hyper-V Administrators' is not in the list.

Comment: For curiosity's sake, at a command prompt on the Hyper-V host run the command `net localgroup "Hyper-V Administrators" "DOMAIN\Hyper-V Administrators" /add`.

Comment: Command just fails giving 'The syntax of this command is...'
I have checked the command quite carefully and all is correct just seems that it cannot see the 'Domain/Hyper-V Administrators' built-in group.

Comment: What's the version of your Active Directory schema? It occurs to me that I'm dealing w/ a pre-Windows 2012 AD schema that doesn't have a "Hyper-V Administrators" as a builtin group but, rather, is a Glocal Group that I created. I suspect that's the crux of the matter here.

Comment: 2012 R2 which does have a built-in 'Hyper-V Administrators' group.  I think we can safely say that is the problem because it is a built-in group.  Have now done the same but with our own 'Hyper-V Admins' group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a domain group to a local group on a domain-joined computer.

Comment: But not apparently Built-in domain groups which I now realise is what I have been trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can nest domain groups in local groups, and this is indeed usual practice: whenever a computer joins a domain, the "Domain Admins" group is automatically placed in the local "Administrators" group; this is how domain admins get their privileges on all domain-joined computers.